# Chrome extension run js in new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://mywebsite.com" })
```

How i can run this js in the new created tab?

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
  code: "document.getElementById('test').value='test';"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a tab, you can pass a callback function that receives the newly created tab for manipulation. This tab has an `id` which can be used to specify which tab the script should be executed in. Unless you specify a tab ID, the script will be executed in the current tab instead of the newly created one.
Therefore what you want is roughly

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://mywebsite.com" }, tab => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: "document.getElementById('test').value='test';"
  });
});
```

Or more elegantly

```
function createTab(options) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.tabs.create(options, resolve);
  });
}

async function main() {
  const tab = await createTab({ url: "https://mywebsite.com" });

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: "document.getElementById('test').value='test';"
  });
}

main();
```

See the [Chrome Tab API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-Tab) for details.